# Grant and Revoke SQL server roles

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to automate granting and revoking server roles for user accounts via a web page.
The details entered in the page will be stored in a SQL table and I have a job created to pick required information from the table and grant/revoke the role.
The code is working fine when the table has 1 user information in it.
However I see an issue when the table contains more than one user.

The query I am using to grant role to a user is shown below.

```
DECLARE @epfunc TABLE
(userid SYSNAME,
 access SYSNAME
);
INSERT INTO @epfunc
VALUES
(
(
    SELECT userid
    FROM epfunc
),
(
    SELECT access
    FROM epfunc
)
);
DECLARE @rolename SYSNAME, @membername SYSNAME;
SELECT @rolename = access,
       @membername = userid
FROM @epfunc;

execute sp_addsrvrolemember @membername, @rolename
```

---

The epfunc table has the following columns
"Servername, Instancename, Databasename, Environment, userid, access, startdate, expirydate, Grantedby"

Please assist with this.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @rolename SYSNAME, @membername SYSNAME;
SELECT @rolename = access,
       @membername = userid
FROM @epfunc;
```

The above part of code stores  last row of the result when you have multiple rows,so if you have more than one user,it won't work as expected..

I would go with a cursor some thing like below(psuedo code)

```
    declare cursor cs
    for select * from @epfunc

    open cs
    fetch next from cs into 
    @rolename,@membername

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN   
execute sp_addsrvrolemember @membername, @rolename
increment cursor

end
close and deallocate cursor
```

Comment: Hello,Thank you for the assistance. I got an error now mentioning that the cursor and increment is not recognized. Troubleshooting this now and will come back once resolved.

Comment: I mentioned it as Pseduo code,look out for cursor examples and implement as needed

Answer (score 0):

```
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON `classicmodels` .* from 'cars'@'localhost';
GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE,CREATE,DROP,INDEX,ALTER,CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE,LOCK
TABLES,CREATE view,EVENT,TRIGGER,show view,CREATE routine,ALTER routine,EXECUTE on `classicmodels`.* TO
'cars'@'localhost';
```